# How can we update the required model field in Django rest framework/Django forms

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-forms

### DRF

I am trying to make update in profile serializers in my models.py 
But when i am trying to update some other fields like bio or address. It says the phone number is already taken.

### DJANGO FORMS

In case of forms if my user's profile is to be updated. I cannot update only email address as it says the field is required.

### Questions

1. Is there is any way to bypass the form / drf.serializers validators
2. Why, when I update my user's email( which is required field in my case) says "The username is already taken".

Comment: yeah you can surely, but please add code from your `views`, `serializers` and `models`.

Comment: Normally you should be able to use PUT or PATCH request to update your model instance if your view allows those requests. If you show us some code, we could say more about your problem.